# How can I set the tabindex of an HTML element so that it corresponds to the next element in the tab order?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code you can see a simplified working example of a table where each row has an options button which triggers a menu with more buttons. However, when you try to tab through the focusable elements you will see that despite opening the menu, you will still have to tab through all the rows before you get into the menu.

My desired result is that you if you for example are focusing the "options" button in row 1, and then proceed to open it, the next tab press should bring you into the first button of the menu. Then as you tab through all the buttons of the menu, you should then be brought back to the "options" button in row 2.

How do I achieve this?

*(Also, I cannot remove the `overflow: hidden` from the table which is why I am using an absolutely positioned menu outside of the table element in the first place)*

```js
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
const table = document.getElementById("table");
const option_buttons = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll("button"));

table.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (option_buttons.includes(e.target)) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    menu.style.top = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
    menu.style.display = "flex";

    document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target !== menu && !menu.contains(e.target)) {
        menu.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #ccc;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 11rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #ccc;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.menu::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -0.75rem;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 0.75rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.75rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.75rem solid #ccc;
}

button:focus {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <button class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <button class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <button class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 4</span>
    <button class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 5</span>
    <button class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <button type="button">View</button>
  <button type="button">Edit</button>
  <button type="button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: When then menu opens, call `.focus()` on the first menu item? I suggest not messing with `tabindex`; that way lies madness.

Comment: @HereticMonkey With this solution, if you tab through the menu, you unfortunately don't end up in the next row. Same problem if you try to tab backwards, the row you were in gets lost.

Comment: You really need to trap the focus to the menu as in a modal dialog (as in [How do I trap focus in Javascript to a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75410940/215552))

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved everything I outlined in my post in this solution. I am using "focus managers" at the start/end of each row + at the start/end of the menu to manually pass on the focus.

The only caveats is that it requires that you manually add data attributes to:

- The first focusable element before and after the table
- The first and last focusable elements within all rows
- The first and last focusable elements within the menu

Apart from that, my only concern is that using invisible buttons **may** be a SEO/Accessibility issue (I don't know)

PS: This solution also assumes you do not need the rows themselves to be focusable.

```js
class Table {
  constructor(elm_table, elm_menu, elm_table_prev_focusable, elm_table_next_focusable) {
    if (!elm_table || !elm_menu || !elm_table_prev_focusable || !elm_table_next_focusable) return;
    this.elm_table = elm_table;
    this.elm_menu = elm_menu;
    this.elm_table_prev_focusable = elm_table_prev_focusable;
    this.elm_table_next_focusable = elm_table_next_focusable;
    
    this.table_option_buttons = Array.from(this.elm_table.querySelectorAll(".btn_option"));
    
    this.row_prev_focus_manager = Object.assign(document.createElement('button'), { type: 'button', id: 'row_prev_focus_manager', className: 'focus_manager' });
    this.row_next_focus_manager = Object.assign(document.createElement('button'), { type: 'button', id: 'row_next_focus_manager', className: 'focus_manager' });
    
    this.menu_prev_focus_manager = this.elm_menu.querySelector("#menu_prev_focus_manager");
    this.menu_next_focus_manager = this.elm_menu.querySelector("#menu_next_focus_manager");
    
    this.menu_first_focusable_elm = this.elm_menu.querySelector("[data-menu-first-focusable]");
    this.menu_last_focusable_elm = this.elm_menu.querySelector("[data-menu-last-focusable]");
    
    this.elm_table.addEventListener("focusin", (e) => {
      const parent_row = this.get_parent_row(e.target);
      if (parent_row) {
        this.set_row_as_active(parent_row);
      }
    });
    
    this.elm_table.addEventListener("focusout", (e) => {
      const old_parent_row = this.get_parent_row(e.target);
      const cur_parent_row = this.get_parent_row(e.relatedTarget);
      if (old_parent_row && old_parent_row !== cur_parent_row) {
        this.set_row_as_inactive(old_parent_row);
      }
    });
    
    this.row_prev_focus_manager.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
      const target_row = this.get_parent_row(e.target);
      const prev_row = target_row.previousElementSibling;
      if (this.elm_menu.is_open && this.elm_menu.target_row === prev_row) {
        this.menu_last_focusable_elm.focus();
      } else {
        if (prev_row) {
          this.get_row_last_focusable(prev_row).focus();
        } else {
          this.elm_table_prev_focusable.focus();
        }
      }
    });
    
    this.row_next_focus_manager.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
      const target_row = this.get_parent_row(e.target);
      if (this.elm_menu.is_open && this.elm_menu.target_row === target_row) {
        this.menu_first_focusable_elm.focus();
      } else {
        const next_row = target_row.nextElementSibling;
        if (next_row) {
          this.get_row_first_focusable(next_row).focus();
        } else {
          this.elm_table_next_focusable.focus();
        }
      }
    });
    
    this.menu_prev_focus_manager.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
      this.get_row_last_focusable(this.elm_menu.target_row).focus();
    });
    
    this.menu_next_focus_manager.addEventListener("focus", (e) => {
      if (e.relatedTarget === this.elm_table_next_focusable) {
        this.menu_last_focusable_elm.focus();
        return;
      }
      const next_row = this.elm_menu.target_row.nextElementSibling;
      if (next_row) {
        this.get_row_first_focusable(next_row).focus();
      } else {
        this.elm_table_next_focusable.focus();
      }
    });
    
    this.elm_table.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (this.table_option_buttons.includes(e.target)) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        this.elm_menu.style.top = e.target.getBoundingClientRect().top + "px";
        this.elm_menu.style.display = "flex";
        this.elm_menu.is_open = true;
        this.elm_menu.target_row = this.get_parent_row(e.target);

        document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          if (e.target !== this.elm_menu && !this.elm_menu.contains(e.target)) {
            this.elm_menu.style.display = "none";
            this.elm_menu.is_open = false;
            this.elm_menu.target_row = null;
          }
        });
      }
    });
    
  }
  
  get_parent_row(elm) {
    return !elm ? null : elm.closest(".row");
  }
    
  get_row_first_focusable(row) {
    return row.querySelector("[data-row-first-focusable]");
  }
  
  get_row_last_focusable(row) {
    return row.querySelector("[data-row-last-focusable]");
  }
  
  set_row_as_active(row) {
    if (!row.is_active) {
      row.is_active = true;
      row.insertBefore(this.row_prev_focus_manager, row.firstChild);
      row.appendChild(this.row_next_focus_manager);
    }
  }
  
  set_row_as_inactive(row) {
    row.is_active = false;
    if (row.contains(this.row_prev_focus_manager) && row.contains(this.row_next_focus_manager)) {
      row.removeChild(this.row_prev_focus_manager);
      row.removeChild(this.row_next_focus_manager);
    }
  }
}

const my_table = new Table(
  document.getElementById("table"),
  document.getElementById("menu"),
  document.querySelector("[data-table-prev-focusable]"),
  document.querySelector("[data-table-next-focusable]"),
);
```

```css
.table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.table > .row:first-child {
  border-top: 0.0625rem solid #ccc;
}
.table > .row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #ccc;
}


.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 11rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #ccc;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.menu::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -0.75rem;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 0.75rem solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 0.75rem solid transparent;
  border-right: 0.75rem solid #ccc;
}


.focus_manager {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}


button:focus {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-table-prev-focusable>Prev Focusable Element</button>

<br><br><br>

<div class="table" id="table">
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <button data-row-first-focusable data-row-last-focusable class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <button data-row-first-focusable data-row-last-focusable class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <button data-row-first-focusable data-row-last-focusable class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 4</span>
    <button data-row-first-focusable data-row-last-focusable class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Item 5</span>
    <button data-row-first-focusable data-row-last-focusable class="btn_option" type="button">Options</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <button type="button" id="menu_prev_focus_manager" class="focus_manager"></button>
  <button type="button" data-menu-first-focusable>View</button>
  <button type="button">Edit</button>
  <button type="button" data-menu-last-focusable>Delete</button>
  <button type="button" id="menu_next_focus_manager" class="focus_manager"></button>
</div>

<br><br><br>

<button type="button" data-table-next-focusable>Next Focusable Element</button>
```

Comment: By using the trick outlined [here](https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/) I was able to insert the html of the menu into the row it was opened by that way the tab order works naturally. Positioning remains the same.